# Characteristic functions of character sheaves on tori

Tags: reference-request, geometric-representation-theory, character-sheaves

I am currently reading a set of lecture notes by V. Ostrik and G. Williamson, [Character sheaves, tensor categories and non-Abelian Fourier transform](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/geordie/Ostrik.pdf). In Theorem 1.1, they make the assertion that the characteristic function $\chi_{\mathcal{L}, \phi}$ is a character of the finite torus $T(\mathbb{F}_q)$. Does anyone know of a reference for a proof of this result, preferably one where the details are all worked out?

Comment: I think this is follows from 2.1.4 (see also 2.3.1) in Mars--Springer. This Prop-2.1.4 says that you can view a Kummer local system as the local system $E_{\theta}$ whose functions--sheaves correspondence image is a character $\theta$ of $T^F$ (the latter is a standard construction which should be found, e.g. in Kiehl--Weissauer's book). One advantage of using Kummer local systems, instead directly with the $E_{\theta}$, is that you are really working with the geometric object $T$ (and hence all $T^{F^i}$), instead of a single finite group $T^F$.